How can I set up secrets with GKE?
I have a .env file of many of the secrets used in a python container running on GKE, but os.getenv() always returns None. Is it possible to load these secrets into GKE, where they can be accessed by the container? (I also have a solution that allows for one container secret that is used to access a database.)

You may consider these objectives to store sensitive data used by GKE clusters as secrets:

Create a secret in Google Cloud Secret Manager.

Create a GKE Autopilot cluster, Kubernetes namespaces, and Kubernetes service accounts.

Create IAM Allow policies to grant access to your Kubernetes service accounts on the secret.

Use test applications to verify service account access.

Run a sample app that accesses the secret using the Secret Manager API.


